# Does sqlite3 has analogue MySQL's CONVERT_TZ function?

Tags: sqlite

I get exception when try to use CONVERT_TZ in RoR project:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: CONVERT_TZ`

Is there some function in sqlite for convert timezone in a query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316845/how-to-insert-datetime-with-timezone-to-sqlite

Comment: This is useless for me. I have all dates as the UTC±0 format in the database. How I can convert them to UTC+3 with sqlite function?

Comment: What exactly is the format of your dates? Is it `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`, or unixtime, or julian day, or something else?

Comment: I have ```YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS``` format.

Answer (score 2):

To convert from `UTC+0` to `UTC+3`:

```
SELECT datetime(columnName, '+3 hour') || '+03:00' AS myDate FROM tableName;
```

Explanation:

```
datetime(columnName, '+3 hour')
```

Above does the translation of hours, it simply tells SQLite to add 3 hours to the initial date. This would not be enough, because it only modifies date, without really telling that the timezone has changed, so we can do it manually, by appending `'+03:00'` to the final date string.

It makes the following conversion from `2015-03-05 15:03:43` to `2015-03-05 18:03:43+03:00`

That means that the date format will change from `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[+/-]HH:MM`, which is a correct datetime format for SQLite, according to its documentation.

Read SQLite's documentation about date functions for any details, or just ask in comments and I can try to help even further. I don't want to paste the entire documentation page here.