# Datetime string format for ActiveRecord fixture (non-Rails)

Tags: ruby, datetime, activerecord, fixtures

Rails apparently provides an extension to `Time.to_s` allows you format the timestamp in a database-friendly way, e.g. `Time.now.to_s(:db)`. This can be used in an ActiveRecord dynamic fixture:

```
my_record:
  some_datetime: <%= Time.utc(2015, 1, 1).to_s(:db) %>
```

However, outside Rails, this fails with

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
  (...) in `to_s'
```

If I'm going to convert the time by hand, what is the format (with time zone etc.) I should be using here?

Alternatively, if I'm wrong and it's not Rails but something in ActiveRecord that adds this extension, what do I need to `require` to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is like this: YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS

Another way to get that format is with strftime:

```
DateTime.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
```

If you want the include timezone, add %z:

```
DateTime.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %z')
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this isn't a Rails feature but rather an ActiveSupport feature. It should work fine in fixtures out of the box; in e.g. IRB you need to `require 'active_support/time'`.

```
$ irb
2.2.2 :001 > Time.utc(2015, 7, 1, 10, 5).to_s(:db)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from (irb):1:in `to_s'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.2 :002 > require 'active_support/time'
 => true 
2.2.2 :003 > Time.utc(2015, 7, 1, 10, 5).to_s(:db)
 => "2015-07-01 10:05:00"
```

However, note that this will drop time zone information:

```
2.2.2 :004 > Time.now.to_s(:db)
 => "2015-08-14 16:21:47"
```

And ActiveSupport's `TimeWithZone` doesn't help:

```
$ irb
2.2.2 :001 > require 'active_support/time'
 => true 
2.2.2 :002 > time_now = Time.now
 => 2015-08-14 16:31:31 -0700 
2.2.2 :003 > time_now_utc = time_now.utc
 => 2015-08-14 23:31:31 UTC 
2.2.2 :004 > time_now_with_zone = Time.now.in_time_zone
 => 2015-08-14 16:31:58 -0700 
2.2.2 :005 > time_now_utc_with_zone = time_now_utc.in_time_zone
 => 2015-08-14 23:31:31 UTC 
2.2.2 :006 > time_now_with_zone.to_s(:db)
 => "2015-08-14 16:31:58" 
2.2.2 :007 > time_now_utc_with_zone.to_s(:db)
 => "2015-08-14 23:31:31"
```

[At least in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13321766/27358), it's on you to make sure your dates are all consistently converted to one time zone before they go into the DB.

Comment: `Time.now.to_s(:db)` worked for me, thanks!